# Updating UIProgressView via delegate method on AudioPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, timer, avaudioplayer, cadisplaylink

I'm attempting to [use `CADisplayLink` to update a `UIProgressView`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29544165/4475605). Here's [`CADisplayLink`'s initialiation signature](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/cadisplaylink)

Here's a summary of the relevant variables from `MyAudioPlayer` class.

```
protocol AudioPlayerDelegate: class {
    func updateSlider(sender: AudioPlayer)
}

class AudioPlayer: NSObject {
    // relevant vars
    var updater: CADisplayLink?
    weak var delegate: AudioPlayerDelegate?

    func play() {
        // some setup stuff

        updater = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(delegate?.updateSlider(sender:)))

        // regular stuff to play an audio file
    }
}
```

When I initialize `updater` in the `play()` method, the compiler says, :

> Argument of `#selector` refers to instance method
>   `updateSlider(sender:)` that is no exposed to Objective-C.

Easy enough...add `objc` in front of `func updateSlider(sender: AudioPlayer)`, like so:

```
@objc func updateSlider(sender: AudioPlayer)
```

The compiler error goes away for a nanosecond, then the the line I just updated says:

> @objc can only be used with members of classes, @objc protocols, and
>   concrete extensions of classes.

There are [a few answers covering this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39818627/4475605), but I haven't found one that works.

I tried throwing `updateSlider` in an extension instead of in the protocol section, but I keep getting this ping pong of the compiler wanting to add `@objc` in front followed by wanting to remove it.

I also attempted to use an instance of the `Timer` class instead of the `CADisplayLink` class to do this, but I encounter the same issue.

Thank you for reading. I welcome your suggestions.

Comment: The protocol needs to marked as @objc, not the method inside it.  Also, the target of your display link should be `delegate` and the selector should be `#selector(AudioPlayerDelegate.updateSlider(sender:))`.  You should also probably unwrap your delegate before passing it to the display link, but I don't know what that method actually does if you pass it nil.

Comment: That was it. I unwrapped the delegate and initialized the CADisplayLink, but the declaring the protocol objc got me over the finish line. I was just declaring the method. Post as an answer to claim your 25. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dan got me over the finish line on this issue. Instead of adding `@objc` in front of just my delegate method, I needed to add `@objc` in front of the protocol declaration.

```
// First change
@objc protocol AudioPlayerDelegate: class {
    @objc func updateSlider(sender: AudioPlayer)
}
```

Further down in the `AudioPlayer` class...

```
// Delegate declaration
weak var delegate: AudioPlayerDelegate?

// Second Change
if let delegate = delegate {
    updater = CADisplayLink(target: delegate, selector: #selector(AudioPlayerDelegate.updateSlider(sender:)))
    updater?.preferredFramesPerSecond = 30
    updater?.add(to: RunLoop.current, forMode: .commonModes)
}
```

Lastly, when done with the `updater`, invalidate it and nil it out (most likely in whatever method you use to stop your AVAudioPlayer instance.

```
    updater?.invalidate()
    updater = nil
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be fixed so :)

```
func play() {
    // some setup stuff

    updater = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(updateSlider(sender:)))

    // regular stuff to play an audio file
}

func updateSlider(sender: AudioPlayer) {
    delegate?.updateSlider(sender: sender)
}
```